# User preferences not saved in Nemo file browser in Linux Mint 14 Cinnamon edition

Tags: linux-mint

I started using Linux Mint 14 (Nadia) recently, and kind of like it better for the Gnome experience its gives using Cinnamon DE.

My question is, the file browser (NEMO 1.1.1) fails the save the defaults - the way I want it to display the folders and stuff. For example, I would like to have the folders listed in the 'List' form instead of the icon format, and would also like to have the "Location Entry" as default, instead of the bread crumbs model address bar in the file browser.

I tried updating the preferences using the Edit > Preferences tool, however the updates are not stored, or getting reflected. I tried restarting Cinnamon, no effect.

Also, I see that there is a toggle button to toggle between the bread crumbs mode and full address typing mode for the address bar, however I couldn't find a place which lets me select which one I need by default.

Please suggest where I need to edit so that these settings can be saved permanently.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the Preferences->Cinnamon Settings->Themes->Other Settings tab

Check: Always Location Entry in Nemo

Restart Nemo

They'll probably move it into the Nemo preferences at some point, as it makes more sense to be in there ...

-G.